# Why would you `replace` rather than assign a new object to the same variable?

Tags: ruby, immutability

I was looking over the Quiz Summary in [Solitaire Cipher](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz1.html), when I stumbled upon this block of code:

```
def triple_cut
  a = @deck.index( 'A' )
  b = @deck.index( 'B' )
  a, b = b, a if a > b
  @deck.replace( [ @deck[(b + 1)..-1],
                   @deck[a..b],
                   @deck[0...a] ].flatten )
end
```

I don't understand why there's a separate method `replace` for this. Why not just do the following?

```
@deck = @deck[(b + 1)..-1] +
        @deck[a..b] +
        @deck[0...a]
```

Why go through the trouble of applying two separate methods (`replace` and `flatten`) when you could just add them together? I didn't run into any problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of ruby is that in a lot of cases there is no right way to do things.  In your case, I think your solution is just as valid as well as being easier to read.

As for `replace`, it works by copying values over into the existing array which is different then assigning it to a different object.

For example

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [3]
x.replace(y) # x is [3] and y is [3]
x << 5 # x is [3, 5] and y is [3]

x = [1, 2]
y = [3]
x = y # x is now pointing to the same object as y
x << 5 # both x and y are [3, 5] because they are the same object
```

Answer (score 5):

1. It saves memory by not re-creating the array.
2. You can refer to the same object without re-assigning the variable.

Comment: 3. Your code requires that the value of the object be changed (maybe 2a).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not quite sure what you mean. You can reassign the same value.

Comment: Your answer seemed (to me) to suggest it is is only an efficiency issue, but the design of your code may of course require that the object to be modified in place.

Answer (score 4):

When replacing/re-assigning large arrays, the `Array#replace` seems to perform better than assignment `=`.

---

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 500
ary_size = 10000

replacement = ['b']*ary_size*3

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { arr = ['a']*ary_size; arr.replace(replacement)} }
  x.report { n.times { arr = ['a']*ary_size; arr = replacement}}
end
```

Output:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002253)
   0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.015224)
[Finished in 0.1s]
```